# Default Password for Generated Users in OpenDJ

Tags: passwords, ldap, opends, opendj

When you create a new 'Base DN' in OpenDJ, OpenDJ allows you to populate the database with automatically generated users.  Does anyone know what the default password for these automatically generated users is?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

When generating sample data with OpenDJ, the data is crafted from a template that you can find under config/MakeLDIF/example.template.
Passwords are by default hardcoded to "password", for all users.
Please check the make-ldif documentation on opendj.forgerock.org for further details.

Regards,

Ludovic

Comment: This is the real answer. I wish question's author would award it to you.